# What OAuth version is the Flickr OAuth API using?

Tags: oauth, flickr

I'm trying to understand the concept of the Flickr OAuth API.
It seems to be based on OAuth 1.0a but if I try to upload an image, they don't ask for the `Access Token` and `Access Token Secret` but just for 1 "OAuth Access Token" (like it's used in OAuth2). 
What concept is it and how do I get that token?

Comment: It is based on OAuth 1.0a. Yes, indeed all your requests will be passed with OAuth Access Token. Put your code here. You may have combined both standards.